How to get the max "width" of a regular polygon in JavaScript?
I have been playing with math equations to draw "regular" polygons (polygons with same length sides and angles). I haven't quite been able to get it to work such that, given a desired width bounding square, the polygon will be no larger than that square based on its "longest dimension".
So for instance, take these two polygons:

Here, the pink width (black lines) is shorter than the blue width (orange lines). So my bounding box will be like this (here in yellow):

That is, the pink square is centered within the bounding box, and the blue square is no larger than the bounding box to fit the corners to the edge.
How can I accomplish this?
I tried these two distance equations to measure the "max distance" in the polygon, but it doesn't do what I am expecting.
export function calculatePolygonHeight(
  sides: number,
  radius: number,
): number {
  // Ensure the number of sides is valid
  if (sides < 3) {
    throw new Error('Number of sides must be at least 3')
  }

  // Calculate the height of the polygon
  const height = radius * (1 + Math.cos(Math.PI / sides))

  return height
}

export function distanceBetweenVertices({
  sides,
  radius,
  distance,
}: {
  sides: number
  radius: number
  distance: number
}): number {
  if (sides < 3) {
    throw new Error('A polygon must have at least 3 sides.')
  }
  if (distance < 1 || distance >= sides) {
    throw new Error('distance must be between 1 and sides-1.')
  }

  const angle = (distance * Math.PI) / sides
  return 2 * radius * Math.sin(angle)
}

To compute SVG polygon paths, I am using this:
function computePolygonPoints({
  width,
  height,
  sides,
  strokeWidth,
  rotation = 0,
}: {
  width: number
  height: number
  sides: number
  strokeWidth: number
  rotation?: number
}) {
  const centerX = width / 2
  const centerY = height / 2
  const radiusX = width / 2
  const radiusY = height / 2
  const offsetX = strokeWidth / 2
  const offsetY = strokeWidth / 2

  const rotationRad = (rotation * Math.PI) / 180

  const points = Array.from({ length: sides }, (_, i) => {
    const angle = (i * 2 * Math.PI) / sides + ANGLE
    const x = centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(angle)
    const y = centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(angle)

    // Apply rotation around the center
    const rotatedX =
      centerX +
      (x - centerX) * Math.cos(rotationRad) -
      (y - centerY) * Math.sin(rotationRad)
    const rotatedY =
      centerY +
      (x - centerX) * Math.sin(rotationRad) +
      (y - centerY) * Math.cos(rotationRad)

    return { x: rotatedX, y: rotatedY }
  })

  const minX = Math.min(...points.map(p => p.x))
  const minY = Math.min(...points.map(p => p.y))

  const adjustedPoints = points.map(p => ({
    x: offsetX + p.x - minX,
    y: offsetY + p.y - minY,
  }))

  return adjustedPoints
}

That correctly draws a polygon (though a separate but related issue, I'm having a hard time adding the stroke width to the calculations, where stroke is centered on the edge, so half the stroke is outside the area of the polygon, and half is inside.
So what I do is (at least what I'm thinking):

Get max distance of polygon somehow.
Offset by strokeWidth/2 (so it doesn't get cut off at the beginning).
Shrink max distance (width) by strokeWidth, so we draw the polygon slightly smaller than we asked, but it is made to look right when strokes are added.

So say I want the polygon to be 256px width, and 8px stroke width. How can I rotate it any way and have it be centered in the bounding box which is 256x256, stretching to fill the bounding box as much as possible?

I've read this question about a dozen times now, and I still have no idea what you're actually trying to calculate. The rotation of the polygon? The radius of the polygon? The size of the bounding box?

"polygons with same length sides and angles" - that means all the vertexes are points on a circle. That circle needs to fit your desired target square, so its center is also the center of the square, and its radius needs to be half the edge length of the square. How to get a point on the circle based on a given angle, should be easy enough to research, if you don't have your school geometry present in memory any more ;-) 360 degrees divided by number of vertexes gives you the angle by which you need to offset them from each other, and for the rotation you can simply add a starting angle ...

@CBroe " That circle needs to fit your desired target square" Only for polygons with an odd number of vertices. For an even number of vertices, the polygon can be rotated by 180/n and the circle can be partially outside the target square while still fitting the entire polygon. But, no idea if that's what OP is trying to achieve as the question is very unclear.

Observe that any regular n-sided polygon is just an approximation of a circle using n vertices, with the distance from the center to any vertex being the same as the circle radius. So: if you know how to do what  you want using a circle (which you do, because that one's easy), then you know how to do what you want using a regular n-sided polygon.

Regular polygons are just n vertices spaced out evenly on a circle, with lines drawn between consecutive vertices, with a distance to the center that by definition equals the circle's radius r, and if you're always going to put the polygonal center in the center of your bounding box (e.g. because you want to spin that sucker around) then the short answer is that you're not interested in the maximum width of the polygon, you're interested in the maximum distance from the center for your polygon, which by definition is r, so your bounding box needs to be 2r wide.
The longer answer is that if you do want the polygon's maximum width, you're dealing with two possible cases: regular n-sided polygons with an even number of vertices, and those with odd vertices. For even numbered polygons we're already done: The maximum width is 2r, measured as the distance from any vertex to its opposite.
For odd numbered polygons, a vertex doesn't have a true opposite, it instead has two opposite vertices that are offset from the line that passes through the vertex and the center. So, to get the maximum width of the polygon, you need to do some trivial trigonometry:
         o
      r /.
       / .
o --- C ..x
   r   \ .
      r \.
         o

The maximum length is r + C--x, which means we need to calculate C--x. We know that the angle Cxo is a right angle, so we apply the "cah" part of "sohcahtoa": we know the hypotenuse because that's r, and we know the angle oCx (because our polygon divides a circle), so C--x is r * cos(2/n * pi), making the maximum width of the polygon r * (1 + cos(2/n * pi)).
And then the even longer answer is that if you want to constantly update the bounding box so that whatever angle your polygon is at, it always perfectly touches your polygon, calculate the axis-aligned maximum width using the same trick.

Not quite sure if I understand that answer, but for even-numbered polygons, the maximum width of the polygon so it can fit the bounding box is not the diameter of the circle that circumscribes the polygon. E.g. a square can be exactly the same size as the bounding box.

Yes, see the last paragraph. If you want "a bounding box that fits your polygon right now", do the math, if you want a bounding box that will fit the polygon "when you do some spinny animations" (or it's already axis-aligned) without constantly changing its orientation, less math required. OP was struggling with how to tackle the problem, this will get them back on track (but I'm not writing their program for them, they now get to do the rest).
